# Content's div does not fully stretch horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

It's my first time using tailwind CSS and I'm not very good at CSS.
I need some help with troubleshooting my design and I couldn't figure out how to stretch the div container according to my screen size

[image]

In this case, I wanted the div content where there table is to stretch until the red line.

Here's my code
Layout.tsx component

```
<div className='min-h-screen bg-bgSecondary'>
            <Head>
                <title>{title}</title>
            </Head>

            {/* Top Navigation Header */}
            <Header />
            <Annoucement />

            {/* Body Content */}
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Announcement.tsx

```
<div>
                <div className='flex w-full bg-yellow-400 shadow-bgTertiary shadow-sm px-4 py-4'>
                    <div className='flex flex-1 max-w-7xl mx-auto uppercase text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 space-x-10 md:space-x-5 space-between items-center'>
                        <div className='flex-1'>
                            <p>Please refrain from <span className='underline font-bold'>sharing your password</span> to anyone.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className='cursor-pointer' onClick={() => setShowAnnoucement(false)}>
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
                                <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

index.tsx

```
<Layout>
      <div className='flex max-w-7xl mx-auto'>
        <div className='py-5 px-5 lg:px-3 2xl:px-0'>
          <div className='text-2xl uppercase font-bold'>
            <h1>Appointments</h1>
          </div>
          <div className='flex flex-col space-y-4 mt-3 outline-none'>
            <Tab.Group>
              <Tab.List className="flex space-x-3">
                <Tab as={Fragment}>
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <button
                      className={
                        (selected ? 'bg-gray-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold' : 'bg-gray-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold')
                      }
                    >
                      Approved
                    </button>
                  )}
                </Tab>
                <Tab as={Fragment}>
                  {({ selected }) => (
                    <button
                      className={
                        (selected ? 'bg-gray-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold' : 'bg-gray-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold')
                      }
                    >
                      Waiting for approval
                    </button>
                  )}
                </Tab>
              </Tab.List>
              <Tab.Panels>
                <Tab.Panel>
                  <table className='border-collapse border border-slate-500 table-auto '>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Song</th>
                        <th className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Artist</th>
                        <th className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Year</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr >
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Malcolm Lockyer</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1961</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Witchy Woman</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>The Eagles</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1972</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Shining Star</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
                        <td className='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1975</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </Tab.Panel>
                <Tab.Panel>Content 2</Tab.Panel>
              </Tab.Panels>
            </Tab.Group>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
```

Comment: What is <LayOut> doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap the whole thing in `container` instead of `flex`. Then inside the container, you can make divs and put them inside flex as per your requirement.

Below is the `tailwind play` implementation of your code which solves the issue.

But to use this code in your `.tsx` file, you have to replace `class` with `className` to see changes in the local system.

Although you can see the demo below also. Please see the page in full view.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class='container p-4'>
  <div class='py-5 px-5 lg:px-3 2xl:px-0'>
    <div class='text-2xl uppercase font-bold'>
      <h1>Appointments</h1>
    </div>
    <div class='flex flex-col space-y-4 mt-3 outline-none'>
      <Tab.Group>
        <Tab.List class="flex space-x-3">
          <Tab as={Fragment}>
            {({ selected }) => (
              <button
                class={
                  (selected ? 'bg-gray-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold' : 'bg-gray-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold')
                }
              >
                Approved
              </button>
            )}
          </Tab>
          <Tab as={Fragment}>
            {({ selected }) => (
              <button
                class={
                  (selected ? 'bg-gray-500 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold' : 'bg-gray-700 px-3 py-2 rounded-md font-bold')
                }
              >
                Waiting for approval
              </button>
            )}
          </Tab>
        </Tab.List>
        <Tab.Panels>
          <Tab.Panel>
            <div class='flex flex-col space-y-4 mt-3 outline-none'>
              <table class='border-collapse border border-slate-500 w '>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class='border border-slate-600 p-3 w-3/5'>Song</th>
                    <th class='border border-slate-600 p-3 w-1/5'>Artist</th>
                    <th class='border border-slate-600 p-3 w-4/5'>Year</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="text-center">
                  <tr >
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>The Sliding Mr. Bones (Next Stop, Pottersville)</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Malcolm Lockyer</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1961</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Witchy Woman</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>The Eagles</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1972</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Shining Star</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>Earth, Wind, and Fire</td>
                    <td class='border border-slate-600 p-3'>1975</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </Tab.Panel>
          <Tab.Panel>
            Content 2
          </Tab.Panel>
        </Tab.Panels>
      </Tab.Group>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```